# CSS is not applied to Custom Tooltips's arrow

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, tooltip

I am using [ReactTooltip](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip)

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wcn9s6)

## Component

```
<ReactTooltip className={styles.customTheme} id={id} place={placement} effect="solid"> 
    {children}
</ReactTooltip>
```

## SCSS

```
.customTheme {
  color: #ff6e00 !important;
  background-color: orange !important;

  &.place-top {
    &::after {
      border-top: 6px solid orange !important;
    }
  }
}
```

## Result

[image]

## Issue

The arrow color is not changed as expected.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the working webpage?

Comment: place-top doesn't sound right, is there a place-bottom?

Comment: @AndyHoffman Please find a working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wcn9s6

Comment: @JoshPittman yes we do have `place-bottom`, but I have to use `place-top`

Comment: The example doesn't work, nothing is orange, scss is not being processed.

Comment: You are applying the colour to `border-top` when you target the triangle, what happens if you just try `border`. Will debug myself once you provide a working example.

Comment: @JoshPittman https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wcn9s6

Comment: This is the same link, the example in this link does not work, if you hover over the text nothing in the tool tip is orange, not even the main bit.

Comment: updated the link

Comment: I have just found out, that it works perfectly in the working link. The issue is with my app. We are using CSS modules and when the class is applied by it the arrow class is doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: Glad we could help :)

Comment: But, the issue is not solved yet. Still facing the issue, in my app.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use "title" in html tag like 
Name:"`<input type="text" title="enter name" />`

Comment: That's a solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Your SCSS just needs the `::before` pseudo-selector.

```
.customTheme {
  background-color: #ff6e00 !important;
  border: 1px solid;
  &.place-top {
    &::before, &::after {
      border-top: 8px solid #ff6e00!important;
    }
  }
```

Note that you should just be able to use the `backgroundColor` and/or `arrowColor` prop on the component, but they're not working: https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/594